# What's the difference between CALayerDelegate displayLayer and NSView updateLayer

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview, appkit

`[CALayerDelegate displayLayer:]` is described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayerdelegate/2097261-displaylayer?language=objc).

`[NSView updateLayer]` is described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483580-updatelayer?language=objc).

How do they differ? When would I use one over the other?

Comment: Relevant answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21081980/2228559

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `-[NSView updateLayer:]`

The purpose of this method is to be overridden by an `NSView` subclass so that you can customize the backing layer. By default, `-[NSView drawRect:]` will be used and you're not supposed to manipulate the backing layer directly (like you might with `UIView` on iOS). If you want to customize the backing layer, you're supposed to use `-updateLayer` and perform your customizations in this method. To opt into using `updateLayer` rather than `drawRect:`, you override `-[NSView wantsUpdateLayer]` and return `YES`. Now you can change any property on the backing layer inside of `-updateLayer`. To notify the view that a change needs to occur you would use the `needsDisplay` property and set it to `YES`, which will trigger `-updateLayer` when it does a render pass. It's also good to know about the `layerContentsRedrawPolicy` property that controls when a redraw is triggered.

Example usage:

```
@implementation MyView

- (BOOL)wantsUpdateLayer {
    return YES;
}

- (void)updateLayer {
    // Perform different customizations based on view/control state.
    self.layer.backgroundColor = NSColor.redColor.CGColor;
    self.layer.contents = <some image>;
}

@end

// Example of notifying MyView instance that it needs to update itself
myView.needsDisplay = YES;
```

Shameless plug of a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iwm47M7st14&list=PLE83F832121568D36&index=72&t=99s) I did on this topic somewhat recently.

#### `-[CALayerDelegate displayLayer:]`

This call is specific to CALayer. If you aren't dealing with NSView, then this is how you can be notified of CALayer needing a change as a result of calling `-[CALayer setNeedsDisplay]`.

In short, if you're dealing with `NSView` and want to have full control over the backing layer, you must override `-wantsUpdateLayer` to return `YES` and implement `-updateLayer`. If you're directly using `CALayer`s (no `NSView` involved), then the delegate can be useful here.

Comment: To clarify, I was asking about the `displayLayer:` method of `CALayerDelegate`, not `CALayer`

Comment: Oh, I see you mention the delegate right at the end. Would it be wrong to make my `NSView` subclass conform to `CALayerDelegate` and implement `displayLayer`? Or is it about the same as implementing `[NSView updateLayer]`?

Comment: It seems that if I override `[NSView makeBackingLayer]`, I'm required to use `[CALayerDelegate displayLayer:]`. Can you confirm this? (Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53288473/2228559)

Comment: @aleclarson Sorry, meant to say CALayerDelegate, there is no call on CALayer. makeBackingLayer is for changing the backing CALayer class used by the NSView and yes you're on your own for managing it via the delegate callbacks. The call should generally be avoided unless you really require a different subclass.

Comment: Alright thanks! Any idea what disadvantages there are to returning `[CALayer layer]` from `makeBackingLayer` instead of using the default `_NSViewBackingLayer` class?

Comment: @aleclarson I've never really dove into the differences between the 2. I image they are rather minimal.

Comment: @aleclarson Don't want to be that guy, but do you think this is an acceptable answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here are my own findings.

If you override `-[NSView makeBackingLayer]`, you **must** use `-[CALayerDelegate displayLayer:]` instead of `-[NSView updateLayer]`.

---

### CALayer vs. NSViewBackingLayer

If you don't override `makeBackingLayer` and you set `wantsLayer` to `YES`, the default layer class is called `_NSViewBackingLayer`.

It behaves differently than `CALayer` in the following ways:

- takes up noticeably less memory.
- calls `setNeedsDisplay:YES` when its `transform` property is set.
- maybe other ways too...?